# Targeting an ID on current page while using <base>?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use a `<base>` tag in a document which has links that have a `:target` effect.  At the moment, the `<base>` tag works, but there are a few "parent" links that I have that when targeted, display a list of "child" links that need to use the `<base>` tag.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3uN8x/)

The issue is that when the `<base>` tag is being used and the parent link is clicked, the browser attempts to navigate to a file named #SFC, instead of staying on the current page and targeting ID SFC.

I'm sure there is an easy fix but I have no idea what to do, and I am relatively new at CSS and this kind of HTML.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659120/url-hash-with-html-base-tag

Comment: I looked at that, but the asker never really gets a helpful answer other than to "remove the base tag" or type out the full address of the page on which the ID is being targeted.  Since these links are supposed to be for navigation purposes, it would be a real pain to have to do that for every page on the site.  I may just change the :target to :hover....

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is kind of the same thing, the base tag will have your link go to www.whatever.com/#SFC. If what you want to do is make the child links visible, I think it would be easier to use :hover or a checkbox.