# Defining HTML <base> URL is hacking all the hashed (#) anchor tag going base

Tags: php, html, hash

I'm stucked in my own [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28199871/1743124) — *it's THE real problem what I wanted to solve*. I defined my `<base>` URL in my PHP project, now all the hashed links

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
     <li role="presentation" class="active">
          <a href="#">Tab Handle</a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

are taking me to the base. It's not just the tab, it's everything: If I provide a hashed `<nav>` element, it's also taking me to the base URL (home URL).
And that's taking a page refresh so, which is another awkward situation.

**How can I solve this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I got a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/659362/1743124). Thanks to @Adam.

```
<base href="http://localhost/project/">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
     <li role="presentation" class="active">
          <a href="javascript:">Tab Handle</a> <!-- it'll work like a hash link -->
     </li>
</ul>
```